# I was working through a BigQuery tutorial, refreshed a page and cannot get it back

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I was doing one of those self-paced tutorials that were offered when I first logged it to guide me through loading data into a storage bucket and copying it into BigQuery from there and so on.  I refreshed the page and it went away and I have not been able to find a way to get it back.  Any idea how to get back to a tutorial I was working through?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the **quickstart** guides for BigQuery in the official GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts).

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/how-to), you can also find all **how-to** guides, related to the BigQuery. For loading data from Cloud Storage into BigQuery in particular, check the section called *"Loading data into BigQuery"* - [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/how-to#loading-data-into-bigquery).

Comment: Thank you for that.  I'll explore the guide.  I will need to figure out how to get data out from a SQL database, but I did end up finding what I was looking for and it was under Add Data just under the Public Data Sources and External Data Sources.  It says Learn how to import data from Google Cloud Storage.